# Should sync API calls be wrapped into async?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, async-await, threadpool

I read some posts and articles on the internet saying that I should not use async until my calls are IO (reading file, sending request, etc.). But if the calling API is actually an IO-related API and does not support async calls, should I wrap them with `Task.Run()`?

Say, if I have MVC server calling an external server via API to get data, but the API does not have async methods. Is there a benefit wrapping sync calls with async in such case?

As I understand, if not wrapping, then all calls to the API are sync and each call to my MVC app uses a thread from thread pool. In second case `Task.Run()` will queue my task onto thread pool, but releases main thread. Is released main thread considered to be benefit here, or it is not worth wrapping? Am I correct here at all?

**EDIT**
Ok, here are some more details as people requested.

I have a third party .NET assembly that I'm forced to use. I can't just call the web-service directly. It looks pretty much like this:

```cs
// the API (I not owner of it, can't change it):
public class Service {
  /* everything is synchronous like this. but somewhere inside
   it still makes HTTP requests to external server, so that's 
   kinda IO. just the lib is very old and doesn't provide async methods*/
  public Data GetData(Paramters parameters);
}

// here comes my code.
// option 1. sync controller
public class MyController {
  public ActionResult GetDataById(string id) {
     var data = new Service().GetData(new Parameters{Id = id});
     // process and return some result ...
  }
}

// option 2. async controller
public class MyController {
  public async ActionResult GetDataById(string id) {
     var result = await Task.Run(() => new Service().GetData(new Parameters{Id = id}));
     // process and return some result ...
  }
}
```

So the question is, does it make sense to do option 2?

Comment: Explain further, Is the API a web API? How are you calling the API from the MVC application? What problem are you trying to solve? You're not gaining any benefit from running synchronous code in an "asynchronous" manner and you are in fact causing a bigger performance degradation as the `ThreadPool` has to queue and consume work. If you can go async natively then you should.

Comment: @ColinM , I've updated my initial question. Thanks.

Comment: In the described scenario you're adding just a bit more overhead for signalling to the `ThreadPool` that it must schedule a new work item, where you will then immediately wait for that work to finish. If it were truly async then you'd have a benefit of being able to queue several work items and await them with `await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2, task3, ...);`

Comment: So basically, it makes no sense. OK, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By wrapping into async, you may get the benefit of making parallel calls to the external server while the actual call would still remain sync , so it would be like multiple threads each waiting on response from external server. I have done this and it could be beneficial when you would like to handle the failures and then the application would not remain stuck in the calling threads.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say if the API itself performs IO related tasks even then having a free main thread would benefit you if the user chooses to perform multiple tasks through the API you would benefit by having the main thread free rather than having it blocked on a single request.